# Does 5e have a Manual of the Planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, lore, planes, feywild

I'm building a Warlock with an Archfey patron, and I want to read more about the Feywild. I remember the AD&D *Manual of the Planes* and it had information from all the planes. Does 5e have one of these? If not, is there a place I can read in-depth about the Archfey and the Feywild? (Similar information on Hell, demon princes, and the Abyss would also be greatly appreciated.)

Comment: Related: [Where can I find more lore about fey and eladrin?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/152986/35259)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### The *Dungeon Master's Guide* and *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* are your best bet

The DMG has a chapter on the planes, which does include the Feywild on pp. 49-50 (and the Nine Hells/Abyss too, pp. 64-66 and 62-63 respectively).

There is more info in MToF on both the Feywild and the Eladrin on pp. 49-50 (what a strange coincidence!), as well as an entire chapter on the Blood War, with plenty of information on devils, demons, the Nine Hells and the Abyss (pp. 5-34).

---

There is also a tiny bit of information on a few Archfey in the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, p. 138, but it's basically just a sentence or two about half a dozen or so possible warlock patrons. Not really worth being a proper part of this answer, but just thought I'd include it for completeness.

Comment: Very helpful as always, thank you. Do you know of anywhere specific I can find info specifically on the Courts and Archfey?

Comment: @SamaraMarkcosian Sadly not, there doesn't seem to be much out there. I included a little mention for the content in SCAG, but it's hardly anything, probably not worth it unless you happen to already own it. So you might be better off looking into lore from older editions (although I'm only really knowledgeable about 5e, so I have no idea what books might help with that).

Comment: @SamaraMarkcosian Actually, the Feywild specifically was added in 4e (according to the footnote on [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/150440/35259) of KRyan's, and I trust that he knows what he's talking about), so if you did want to look at lore from previous editions, you'd need to look at 4e specifically for the Feywild plane. As for Archfey, I'm _think_ they might have existed before 4e and the Feywild, but now I'm just guessing...

Comment: @NathanS There was a little about the Feywild before 4e, under the name "Plane of Faerie", but it wasn't described in much detail until 4e made it a major part of the D&D cosmology. The result is that most Feywild canon was first laid down in 4e.

Comment: Note: The adventure *The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*, set in the Feywild, has been released since the answer was posted. I haven't read/played the adventure, so I'm not sure how much relevant material there is. There's also *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* for info on the Nine Hells, though that info's mostly about Avernus. It might be useful to add some info about either/both of those. (There's also *Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse*, but to my knowledge, the info there is mostly about Sigil and the Outlands.)

Answer (score 6):

No. At this time, there is no equivalent to the *Manual of the Planes*.

However, *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* does contain info about demons and devils with regards to The Blood War. There is also info about the Feywild and it's occupants. In my opinion, not enough.

Comment: Note: The adventure *The Wild Beyond the Witchlight*, set in the Feywild, has been released since the answer was posted. I haven't read/played the adventure, so I'm not sure how much relevant material there is. There's also *Baldur's Gate: Descent into Avernus* for info on the Nine Hells, though that info's mostly about Avernus. It might be useful to add some info about either/both of those. (There's also *Planescape: Adventures in the Multiverse*, but to my knowledge, the info there is mostly about Sigil and the Outlands.)

Answer (score 5):

#### Some books from earlier editions of D&D might be useful

A lot of the lore from sourcebooks for earlier editions of D&D may still be useful for D&D 5th edition campaign. Much of this lore has been retained in current D&D canon, though it is explored more thoroughly in the older sourcebooks.

The D&D 4th edition *Manual of the Planes* (2008) has 16 pages on the Feywild and the major archfey and important realms. The Feywild is largely an invention of D&D 4th edition, though it is synonymous with the Plane of Faerie, which was mentioned only briefly in earlier sourcebooks. The 5e lore on the Feywild is [largely the same as 4e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141681/40971), with minor changes to things like the name of Queen Titania (Tiandra).

For the realms of demons and devils, the absolute best sources are the D&D 3rd edition *Fiendish Codex I* and *Fiendish Codex II*. The 3rd edition *Manual of the Planes* and *Book of Vile Darkness* also have information on these topics, as do numerous AD&D *Planescape* sourcebooks including *Hellbound*.

Dragon magazine also ran a *Demonomicon of Iggwilv* article series detailing specific demon princes in issues 329, 333, 337, 341, 345, 349, 353, 357, and 359; in the digital Dragon issues 360, 364, 369, 376; and in the digital Dungeon issues 172, 188, 205, and 208.

The *Codex of Betrayal* series similarly detailed archdevils, appearing in digital Dragon issues 365, 373, 427, and 428; and digital Dungeon issues 176 and 197. If I'm not mistaken, you can still pay for a single month of the 4e *D&D Insider* service and download the entire back-catalogue of Dragon 360 onward and Dungeon 151 onward.

The *Court of Stars* article series also describes powerful archfey. It appears in digital Dragon issues 374, 420, 422 and 428; and digital Dungeon issues 185, 196, and 205.

The [Planescape Index](http://www.rilmani.org/psIndex.txt) can also help you to find AD&D 2e and D&D 3e sources for specifics on planar topics.

Comment: To expand this a tiny bit. The Court of Stars (who reside mostly but not always in Arborea) are where most Fey-Powers resided prior to the Feywild becoming ubiquitous. In any of the D&D planar sources you may find that many similar-to-arch-fey entities often reside on the Chaotic Planes, mostly the Chaotic Good Planes. Arborea/Olympus, and to lesser degrees the Beastlands, and Elysium. The Unseelie court resides in pandemonium.

Answer (score 1):

### The Wild Beyond the Witchlight

The definitive 5e resource for the Feywild is **[The Wild Beyond the Witchlight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/adventures/the-wild-beyond-the-witchlight).**
(Sept 2021)  This is "[the first 5th Edition adventure set in the Feywild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Beyond_the_Witchlight)"and takes PCs from 1st to 8th level.  It describes "Prismeer, a Feywild domain of delight" and mentions the archfey Zybilna.  It includes two new character races — the fairy and the harengon, two new character backgrounds — the Feylost and the Witchlight Hand.

There is also Unearthed Arcana playtest material in **[Folk of the Feywild](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/UA2021_FeyFolk.pdf).**
(May 2021)  It presented the Fairy, the Hobgoblin, the Owlfolk, and the Rabbitfolk (later harengon) as playable options.

A charity expansion is **[Domains of Delight](https://www.dndbeyond.com/marketplace/sourcebooks/domains-of-delight-a-feywild-accessory).**
It is an optional add-on to The Wild Beyond the Witchlight and establishes additional information on the Feywild such as the Seelie and Unseelie Courts, Fey Gifts and Hospitality, and Fey contracts.  [It also includes](https://www.thegamer.com/feywild-domain-of-delight-with-dungeons-dragons-charity-accessory/) information on building Feywild domains, creating an archfey, and converting pre-existing stat blocks into Fey themed stat blocks.